# android/ios chat application server side implementation in java

Tags: java, serversocket

I want to create a server side implementation where multiple clients (android or ios )  can make chat on events which they are part of , which server side implementation is preferred for same , Can anyone suggest me the framework , currently i have implemented multi threaded socket programming at server, server listen on particular port for same.

I want application to work for thousands of users at the same time , Is there any open source chat framework available ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best frameworks to work with many clients is **Netty**:

http://netty.io/

It is a NIO framework, which simplifies the development of large scalable applications. It provides a lot of protocol implementations out of the box, and allows you to develop your own protocols in case you need those. In case of a chat application, this is a good option.

If you are already looking for a pre-implemented chat server, this is not it. But Netty framework can be used for that easily.